# Write dataframe to Teradata in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, teradata

I have values in dataframe , and I have created a table structure in Teradata. My requirement is to load dataframe to Teradata. But I am getting error:

I have tried following code :

```
df.write.format("jdbc")
  .option("driver","com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver")
  .option("url","organization.td.intranet")
  .option("dbtable",s"select * from td_s_zm_brainsdb.emp")
  .option("user","userid")
  .option("password","password")
  .mode("append")
  .save()
```

I got an error :

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:93)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:518)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:215)
>   ... 48 elided

I changed url option to make it similar to jdbc url, and ran following command:

```
df.write.format("jdbc")
  .option("driver","com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver")
  .option("url","jdbc:teradata//organization.td.intranet,CHARSET=UTF8,TMODE=ANSI,user=G01159039")
  .option("dbtable",s"select * from td_s_zm_brainsdb.emp")
  .option("user","userid")
  .option("password","password")
  .mode("append")
  .save()
```

Still i am getting error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:93)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:518)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:215)
>   ... 48 elided

I have included following jars:

```
with --jars option 
tdgssconfig-16.10.00.03.jar
terajdbc4-16.10.00.03.jar
teradata-connector-1.2.1.jar
```

Version of Teradata 15
Spark version 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JDBC Url should be in the following form :

```
val jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:teradata://${jdbcHostname}/database=${jdbcDatabase},user=${jdbcUsername},password=${jdbcPassword}"
```

It was causing an exception, because I didn't supply username and password.

Answer (score 1):

Change the jdbc_url and dbtable to the following

```
.option("url","jdbc:teradata//organization.td.intranet/Database=td_s_zm_brainsdb)
.option("dbtable","emp")
```

Also note in teradata, there are no row locks, so the above will create a table lock. i.e. it will not be efficient - parallel writes from sparkJDBC are not possible.

Native tools of teradata - fastloader /bteq combinations will work.
Another option - that requires a complicated set up is Teradata Query Grid - this is super fast - Uses Presto behind the scene.

Comment: 1- I am using Dataframe writer, my requirement is to read from table. How 'select * from table' will make difference?

Comment: I updated it. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html describes the syntax of jdbc write as well.

Comment: Thanks for help. But with this configurations also, I am getting an error - java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:93)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:518)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:215)
  ... 48 elided

Comment: Is your read working? Want to be sure you are able to connect to teradata

Comment: No, reading is also not working. It either means , I am missing some option in jdbc parameter , or version of jars are not in sync with version of teradata and hadoop. I am using teradata 14 and HDP 2.x

Answer (score 1):

Below is code useful while reading data from Teradata table,

```
   df = (spark.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver")
   .option("url", "jdbc:teradata//organization.td.intranet/Database=td_s_zm_brainsdb")
   .option("dbtable", "(select * from td_s_zm_brainsdb.emp) AS t")
   .option("user", "userid")
   .option("password", "password")
   .load())
```

This will create data frame in Spark.

For writing data back to database below is statement,

## Saving data to a JDBC source

```
jdbcDF.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:teradata//organization.td.intranet/Database=td_s_zm_brainsdb") \
    .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename") \
    .option("user", "username") \
    .option("password", "password") \
    .save()
```

Comment: I have to write data back to teradata,  not to read from teradata.